# Why is my MacBook Pro 13" 2019 (A1989) not powering on?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, hardware, sleep-wake, charging

I left my macbook on charge after putting it to sleep. Later when I'm trying on turn it on, it's simply refusing to turn on. There are just no signs of life.

First I checked the charger and cable, they're all good and are able to charge other devices very well. Also, I am measuring the current drawn by the charger and it is not consuming any power when plugged into macbook, it just sits idle no matter how long it's plugged in.

Next I tried SMC resetting several times for T2 chip macbooks as mentioned on Apple's website, but that absolutely did nothing.

Finally I opened up the back cover and found that the battery is swollen (I am sure it has been swollen since a long time before this issue happened because the lid wasn't closing neatly but did after I open the back cover), still I just unplugged both battery power connector and logic connector between battery board and motherboard and left it for 5 minutes and put everything back together, no signs of turning on. Again tried SMC reset and everything but no signs of life.

I need to bring it to life ASAP, would really appreciate your help here.

Comment: You have a physical defect with your battery that needs to be fixed.  The fact that you find yourself in the unique position of needing to access your data immediately, doesn't change this - until you get the battery repaired, there's no  workaround.